# Regarding IOS App Store and Google Store Promo Codes

Tags: android, ios, google-play, app-store

Have a question regarding promo codes for the IOS App Store and Google Play Store.

Basically intention is to create a discount off the original price of the IAP(In-App-Purchase), for example from 2 dollars, to give a 50% discount, so the customer will pay only 1 dollar for the App Item.

I've checkedout out IOS (100 promo codes per version) and Google Play Store (500/quarter).

However I don't see any place where I can key in either a percentage discount, or set the price of the IAP after the customer applies the promo code.

Does anyone know how I can implement such a promotion on the apps?

Thanks and appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no any property for percentage discount in in-app purchases in both the platform. 
You need to create another in-app purchase which price is 50% of your original price.